# Forwarding between two domains pointed to the same directory of the server without changing the URL

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, .htaccess

I have `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`.

`domain1.com` is the main domain that is pointed to the server IP `123.123.123.123` exactly to the directory `public_html`.

`domain2.com` is the domain that I want to forward to `domain1.com` without changing the URL in the user's browser. (Note: this domain will be the domain of the user profile).

So, instead of typing `domain1.com/users/John`, I will type `domain2.com`.

`domain2.com` is pointed to the same IP address `123.123.123.123` and to the same directory of `domain1.com` (`public_html`).

I pointed `domain2.com` to the same server and directory to access it from the htaccess of `domain1.com`.

So, I tried the following in the `.htaccess` of `public_html`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain1.sa/users/John/$1 [P]
```

But this is returning 500 Error http code!

Note: I have a dedicated server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com
> RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain1.sa/users/John/$1 [P]
> ```

It's not clear why this would result in a 500 error, unless mod_proxy or mod_rewrite is not installed or configured properly? Or you have a conflict with other directives perhaps? You should check your error log for the specifics of the error.

However, if the two domains point to the same server/directory and you wish to keep `domain2.com` (the original URL) in the browser's address bar, then you shouldn't have to proxy the request (as you are trying to do here). A simpler internal rewrite (on the same domain) would seem to be all you require. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com
RewriteRule !^users /users/John%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The regex `!^users` is to avoid a rewrite-loop (which will also manifest itself as a 500 error in the browser).

> So, instead of typing `domain1.com/users/John`, I will type `domain2.com`.

But note that the above will send the request to `/users/John/` (with a trailing slash), not `/users/John` (no trailing slash) as you've stated here - is that an issue?

And you are wanting to rewrite from `/<something>` to `/users/John/<something>` - as per the code sample you posted? Although this is not mentioned in your question text? If you only want to rewrite requests for the domain itself, ie. `domain2.com/` and not `domain2.com/<something>` then the above can be simplified further. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com
RewriteRule ^$ /users/John [L]
```